# Why consider only direction cosines?

Tags: vectors

Well!why do we consider only direction cosines and not direction sines or tans.
What is its actual significance?and how to use them?

Answer (score 4):

Good question. According to the definition, direction cosines give the cosines of the angles which the vector makes with the positive $x,y,z$ axes. The angles range between $0$ and $180$ degrees and they give a unique direction of the vector.

If you see, $\cos x$ is continuous and takes distinct values in $[0,\pi]$ and that's what distinguishes it from $\sin$ and $\tan$.

Answer (score -1):

Bcoz, when we consider either sines or tans unlike coses, we involve opposite side which depends on the plane we consider in measuring alpha, beta and gamma.

For eg:
We can measure alpha in either XY or XZ plane(a plane containing X as one of its axis).

So, $sin(\alpha)$ in XY =$\frac{b}{a}$;

$sin(\alpha)$ in XZ =$\frac{c}{a}$

So involving opposite side does not give a unique line.

Comment: Please, typset mathematical expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you have trouble writing in English you could try using [google translate](https://translate.google.com/)